# Command status 69 error while sending SMS

Tags: node.js, smpp

I am using node-smpp for sending SMS. I have 2 accounts. One for marketing SMS and One for transactional SMS. Everything was working fine. I send around 6000 SMS from both accounts at a time. But suddenly I am not able to send SMS through my Transactional account. The promotional account is working fine. Now I am getting the following PDU response if I send SMS through my transactional account.

```
PDU {
command_length: 17,
command_id: 2147483652,
command_status: 69,
sequence_number: 3,
command: 'submit_sm_resp',
message_id: ''
}
```

Do you guys have any idea what's the issue?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code 69 is submit_sm or submit_multi failed which doesn't really help you much. If the code is identical between the two accounts (and I would validate that), then obvious answer is that something changed for your transactional account.  My first guess would be that the account is being throttled.  Do you have a way validate that the account is in good standing?  Do you handle the error event?  The command is a response.  Are you responding to message?  Why is message_id the empty string?  Do you get the same behavior for different message (i.e. does this happen for all receivers or only some)?